# Iterate through nested JSON object and get values throughout

Tags: python, json, parsing

Working on a API project, in which I'm trying to get all the redirect urls from an API output such as https://urlscan.io/api/v1/result/39a4fc22-39df-4fd5-ba13-21a91ca9a07d/

Example of where I'm trying to pull the urls from:

```
"redirectResponse": {
  "url": "https://www.coke.com/"
```

I currently have the following code:

```
import requests
import json
import time

#URL to be scanned
url = 'https://www.coke.com'

#URL Scan Headers
headers = {'API-Key':apikey,'Content-Type':'application/json'}
data = {"url":url, "visibility": "public"}
response = requests.post('https://urlscan.io/api/v1/scan/',headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))

uuid = response.json()['uuid']
responseUrl = response.json()['api']

time.sleep(10)

req = requests.Session()
r = req.get(responseUrl).json()
r.keys()

for value in  r['data']['requests']['redirectResponse']['url']:
    print(f"{value}")
```

I get the following error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`. Not sure what the best way to parse the nested json in order to get all the redirect urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `redirectResponse` isn't always present in the `requests`, so the code has to be written to handle that and keep going. In Python that's usually done with a `try`/`except`:

```
for obj in r['data']['requests']:
    try:
        redirectResponse = obj['request']['redirectResponse']
    except KeyError:
        continue  # Ignore and skip to next one.
    url = redirectResponse['url']
    print(f'{url=!r}')
```